# Using Flexslider twice on a page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, flexslider, multiple-instances

Hi I am wanting to use the flexslider twice on a page. I found this tutorial: http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/comment/reply/33 But havent had any luck. Below is the code I have in the functions file. Anyone know where I might be going wrong?

```
function anaximander_flexslider() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

        // Enqueue FlexSlider JavaScript
        wp_register_script('jquery_flexslider', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery_flexslider');

        // Enqueue FlexSlider Stylesheet        
        wp_register_style( 'flexslider-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/CSS/flexslider.css', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider-style' );

        // FlexSlider custom settings       
        add_action('wp_footer', 'anaximander_flexslider_settings');

        function anaximander_flexslider_settings() { ?>         
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(window).load(function() {
    $('#main-slider').flexslider({
      animation: 'slide',
      controlsContainer: '.flex-container'
    });

    $('#logo-slide-show').flexslider();
  });
            </script>
        <?php 
        }

    }
}

add_action('init', 'anaximander_flexslider');
```

Comment: Does it work with one instance? Is the javascript being loaded correctly? Any errors in the console?

Comment: No, doesn't work at all - looks like the javascript is not being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in your function the control and animation of the flexslider is based on element Ids like '#main-slider' . But if you use the slider twice there will be a conflict because of 2 same ids.

What you need to make 2 independant sliders with different ids, and have 2 different 'anaximander_flexslider()' to generate them.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so fast.I see - so does this mean creating a separate function for each slider?

Comment: Yes. but in fact it will be more complicated because you enqueue the scripts in the function. The fact is you may need to modify flexslider scripts to pass id of the slider you want to control. It's kind of weird i know. Flexslider has been created to be used only once in page.

Comment: Damb - that sounds a bit complicated for me, I am new to javascript, but many thanks for your help.

Comment: The simplier way is to make a template page which includes directly a hand writtened flexslider.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps that I would take:

1. Check the console in Firebug - are there any errors?
2. Check the HTML in Firebug - are the scripts being loaded? If not, check the paths
3. Replace Flexslider with a jQuery plugin that allows multiple instances; Cycle or [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) are great workhorses of the slider world
4. Take the `anaximander_flexslider_settings` function out of the other function so it can be called independently
5. If it's still not working, put the `wp_enqueue_script, wp_register_script` etc directly in the header, and then once you've got it working you can call them with functions and hooks again, to rule out any issues there.